# Change style attribute on browser window maximisation

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress [website](http://www.srcthor.nl) that uses a responsive theme. The menu of that theme is in a div `#main-nav` that appends a style attribute for the `min-height`, so that on smaller screens the menu items can stack on top of each other. The problem I am facing is that when a user maximises his/her screen using the maximise button or windows+arrow up, the style attribute doesn't get adjusted correctly.

I tried implementing the following code, which effectively overrides the theme's min-height functionality, but doesn't seem to work for maximisation either:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() > 991) {
        $('#main-nav').css('min-height', '76px');
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this have to be done with JavaScript or is using a [CSS media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) an option?

Comment: @MarcBaumbach The current scripts appends a style attribute. Doesn't that always supersede CSS?  Sorry for the long wait, forgot to add your name to the comment.